# how to get user defined title in export to excel from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I am exporting data to excel and its working but can't find the way to add column title.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");

$select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM trucks");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
 {
   $data.=$row['rcnumber']."\t";
   $data.=ucfirst($row['owner_name'])."\t";
   $data.=$row['engine_no']."\n";
 }
echo $data;
exit();
```

i tried with array_keys function but didn't work exactly. please provide suggestions.

Comment: Can't you add the headers before the while loop?

Comment: i have added that, please provide some suggestion.

Comment: By headers I meant the column titles, like you asked.